# ClickOnce Deployment for a C++/CLI Project using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008, clickonce, c++-cli

How do I publish a C++/CLI Windows Forms project for ClickOnce deployment? The properties window for C++/CLI projects does not include a "Publish" tab (like in the C# projects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [guidelines for manually deploying a ClickOnce application on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx).

This relies on the Windows Software Development Kit and command line tools instead of Visual Studio to do your deployment.

Just another note with this - if you can, I'd recommend trying to [migrate to /clr:pure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173253(VS.80).aspx) if possible.  If you're working with native code, this won't work, but if it's a pure windows forms app, it will make the deployment scenario simpler, since you'll have fewer issues in ClickOnce with CAS requirements.

Comment: Ya, PURE it is.  Unfortunately my experience has been the primary benifit of C++/CLI is for managed/native I/O.  PURE's model is usually prohibative :(  It's actually one of my pet peeve's, this and the lack of 64bit/32bit mixed mode debugging support.. :|

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ClickOnce deploy an exe written in unmanaged code.  The standard approach is to create a managed code stub exe that would launch your actual application.

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686/is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-native-delphi-application-with-clickonce).